# ulimit & rlimit in Linux, are they the same thing?

Tags: linux, kernel, performance, resources, ulimit

I see people use the terms `ulimi`t & `rlimit` interchangeably, can I say they are referring to the same thing?

Comment: Related: [ulimit: difference between hard and soft limits](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29577/ulimit-difference-between-hard-and-soft-limits)

Answer (score 14):

I think the confusion comes from the fact that the underlying system call that ulimit wraps is called [setrlimit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setrlimit.html).

*excerpt from the [ulimit man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ulimit.html)*

> The ulimit() function shall control process limits. The process limits
>   that can be controlled by this function include the maximum size of a
>   single file that can be written (this is equivalent to using
>   setrlimit() with RLIMIT_FSIZE).

Additionally if you look at the `setrlimit` man page the underlying data structure which contains the limit information is called `rlimit`.

*excerpt from the [setrlimit man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit)*

> getrlimit and setrlimit get and set resource limits respectively. Each
>   resource has an associated soft and hard limit, as defined by the
>   rlimit structure (the rlim argument to both getrlimit() and
>   setrlimit()):
>
> ```
> struct rlimit {
>     rlim_t rlim_cur;   /* Soft limit */
>     rlim_t rlim_max;   /* Hard limit (ceiling 
>                           for rlim_cur) */
> };
> ```

#### References

- [ulimit: difference between hard and soft limits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29577/ulimit-difference-between-hard-and-soft-limits)
- [Linux memory limits (rlimits)](http://linuxfollies.blogspot.com/2010/10/linux-memory-limits-rlimits.html)

Answer (score 4):

Referring to [ulimit man page](https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html), it's a bash shell command to control the rlimits of the system and a part of [bash-builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) like printf, read, source, etc.

Referring [getrlimits page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html), it represents the APIs via C/C++ using system calls to control system rlimits. Additional [glibc documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Limits-on-Resources.html) on explains rlimits (= resource limits) better.

Answer (score 2):

`ulimit` can be two things:

- a POSIX 7 C API interface that was deprecated in favor of `getrlimit()`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ulimit.html

  > Applications should use the getrlimit() or setrlimit() functions instead of the obsolescent ulimit() function.

  This was not the case when `sim` answered on POSIX 6.

  On GNU/Linux, `getrlimit()` and `ulimit()` are implemented with the `sys_getrlimit` system call. There is no `sys_ulimit`.
- a non-deprecated POSIX 7 CLI utility: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ulimit.html

  It can be implemented with either `ulimit()` or `getrlimit()`.